# IOS UIImagePicker in a UIView subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, subview

I am trying to display a UIImagePicker from a programatically generated UIView that's added as a subview of the original view controller. The image picker comes up and so does the camera but the functionality breaks and nothing navigates properly.  How do I properly load an image picker from a UIView and not a UIControlView?

code that breaks:

```
- (void)captureImage:(id)sender
{
    [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                 delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Take photo", @"Camera Roll", nil]
     showInView:self];
}

//UIImagePicker specific methods
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            [self takePhoto];
                break;

        case 1:
            [self fromCameraRoll];
                break;
    }
}

-(void)takePhoto
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == YES)
    {
        // Create image picker controller
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        // Set source to the camera
        imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        // Delegate is self
        imagePicker.delegate = self;

        // Show image picker
        [self addSubview:imagePicker.view];
    }
}

-(void)fromCameraRoll
{
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self addSubview:imgPicker.view];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    //do something with the image

    //add code to pick images here and store them in the preview
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: On an iPhone, you are supposed to present the image picker modally (full-screen) using presentViewController:animated:completion:. I don't know whether Apple would approve of presenting it from a smaller view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIImagePickerController is view controller class, you better present your image picker to your parent view controller by a delegate call or something like with an overlay subview to achieve your goal.

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

CustomOverlayView *overlayview = [[CustomOverlayView alloc] init];

imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayview;

[self presentModelViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
```

add another delegate in your overlay class to dismiss your camera picker controller view

```
[imgPicker dismissModelViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Just a quick note, better use [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil]; and [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
since presentModelViewController and dismissModelViewControllerAnimated are deprecated